# Unknown column '*' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to get most downloaded data of my table including other table data and I'm receiving this error

> Unknown column 'pls_all_downloads.downloader_ip' in 'field list'

this is the query I'm trying to make

```
SELECT 

    `pls_all_downloads.downloader_ip` AS total_downs, 
    new_mod.id AS mod_id, 
    new_mod.id, 
    new_mod.mod_photos, 
    new_mod.mod_category, 
    new_mod.mod_subcategory_lv1, 
    new_mod.mod_subcategory_lv2, 
    new_mod.mod_slogan, 
    new_mod.mod_status, 
    new_mod.mod_likes, 
    new_mod.mod_downloads_count, 
    new_mod.mod_name 

    FROM pls_all_downloads AS downloads, 
    pls_mods_data AS new_mod 

    WHERE 
    new_mod.id = downloads.mod_id 
    AND downloaded_time > 1407014656 
    AND new_mod.mod_status = 2 

    GROUP BY new_mod.id ORDER BY total_downs DESC LIMIT 3
```

and this is the pls_all_downloads structure: http://prntscr.com/49wx6x
and this is the pls_mods_data structure: http://prntscr.com/49wxfe

so how should my code look like to work like it's should be?

this is the action when I'm trying to receive few top articles ordering it by downloads of its files.

Comment: are you sure you used the back tic and not the single quote? The error seems to show teh single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you assigned an alias to a table in a `FROM` clause you must use alias, so

```
SELECT downloads.downloader_ip, ...
```

Second thing: you only enclose identifiers in back ticks. So if you want to use back ticks in this query, they must be like

```
`downloads`.`downloader_ip`
```

so that *every* identifier was enclosed separately.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: oh man, this is so good, thanks. `downloads`.`downloader_ip` - helps a lot.

Comment: @user3744738: Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-qualifiers.html, especially the "If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting" part